# Oracle, Updating multiple rows in one query, using prepared statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, prepared-statement

I know that you can insert multiple rows in a query by using

```
  INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Is there a way for update as well based on a value? So it would be something like

```
  UPDATE ALL
  SET mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  SET mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  SET mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (?,?,?)
  WHERE ID= ?
  SELECT * FROM dual;
```

For instance i have a reviewtable

```
       reviewid      bookid     authorname   authoremail
          1            1           peter        wdwdd
          2            1           jane         dwdwdw
          3            1           mary         dwdw
```

Is it possible to do a multiple update where bookid = "1" ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but maybe you simply need [update](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm)

Comment: I don't get this. Are you trying to update several rows to the same values, or to different values? Can you add sample table data, before and after the update(s)?

Comment: use this link http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450

Comment: It still isn't clear, partly because you haven't shown your bind values or what the table would look like afterwards. Your proposed `update all` has three sets of bind variables, so what would those be? It seems to assume there will be exactly three rows for the given `bookid`, and implies you want each of those updated with different values - but how would it know which values to use for which row? And if you're setting them all to the same values, what's wrong with a simple `update`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm):

```
MERGE INTO reviewtable r
USING ( SELECT 1 AS reviewid,
               1 AS bookid,
               'peter smith' AS name,
               'p.smith@email' AS email
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 1, 'jane blogs', 'j.blogs@email' FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 1, 'mary adams', 'm.adams@email' FROM DUAL
      ) src
ON    ( r.bookid = src.bookid AND r.reviewid = src.reviewid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET authorname  = src.name,
      authoremail = src.email;
```